# How to shorten tab bar config codes?

Tags: swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a configuration code for UITabBarItem but it is too much. Is there any way to shorten this code? I couldn't find any extension for that.

```
let selectedColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3921568627, green: 0.168627451, blue: 0.4509803922, alpha: 1)
let deselectedColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5843137255, green: 0.6470588235, blue: 0.6509803922, alpha: 1)
    
let selectedFont = UIFont(name: "SFProDisplay-Bold", size: 10)!
let deselectedFont = UIFont(name: "SFProDisplay-Regular", size: 10)!
    
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: deselectedFont, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : deselectedColor], for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: selectedFont, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : selectedColor], for: .selected)
```

If there are any extensions for UITabBar and UITabBarItems, can you please share them with me?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to get rid of all `NSAttributedString.Key`s, because swift can infer that itself.

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.font: deselectedFont, .foregroundColor : deselectedColor], for: .normal)
```